# How to Limit the Amount of Columns in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

How would I go about Limiting the amount of Columns that an HTML Table can Show.The data is Pulled from an SQL table and it is then displayed in a table but I only want the table to Show 6 In a Row then start a New one Instead it Adds Infinate amounts to the single row how can I get around this?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","Password","Database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menus");
echo "<table width='400'>";
echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo'<td>';

?>

<a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>" class="tip" alt="<?php echo $row['game']; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $row['picture']; ?>" alt="" width="150" height="120" class="fade" />
</td>

<?php
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>
```

Comment: so add some logic to output `</tr><tr>` when you want a new row created. Right now you're just creating one row with an arbitrary number of cells in it.

Comment: @MarcB Hi Yes I have tried using `<tr>` but it just puts all of them in a new row I need 6 on one and then it to start a new one with 6 on that and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
$cols = 0;
echo '<table><tr>';
while($row = fetch()) {
  $cols++;
  if ($cols >= 6) {
     echo '</tr><tr>';
     $cols = 0;
  }
  echo '<td> ...</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Fixed it!! I put a Div around the table and sized it to 6 Images in CSS